# JTextArea Won't Update Unless I Resize JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, jtextarea

Whenever I run my program my JTextArea does not follow the dimension that I have given it, but if I resize my JFrame it updates and sets its size to what I put.

What is the issue?

```
    public ControlPanel() {
    // create our list of players
    list = new JList(model);

    // create our scroll panes
    userspane = new JScrollPane(list);
    consolepane = new JScrollPane(console);

    // set sizes
    userspane.setSize(100, 500);
    jta.setSize(100, 500);
    list.setSize(100, 500);
    consolepane.setSize(100, 500);
    console.setSize(100, 500);

    // add to panel
    panel.add(userspane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(kick);
    panel.add(ban);
    panel.add(info);
    panel.add(consolepane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // set frame properties
    setTitle("RuneShadows CP");
    setSize(280, 400);
    //setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setContentPane(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: _"What is the issue?"_ - You're setting the size to everything. Just `.pack()` and let it do all the sizing for you.

Comment: I used pack() but the second JTextBox still isn't the right size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the sizes to *anything*.

- For `JTextArea` you can use the constructor `JTextArea(int rows, int charSpaces)`
- Just `pack()` the `JFrame` and it will respect all the preferred sizes of the components inside.
- Also instead of setting the content pane to the panel, just add the panel. That will respect the preffered size of the panel when `pack()` is called

I'm not exactly sure what variable was what (or the sizes you wanted the), so I assumed text areas, and others as well. See this example where I just used the `JTextArea` constructor I mentioned and just `pack`ed.

**EDITED** with **no sizes set**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ControlPanel extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane userspane;
    JList list;
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JScrollPane consolepane;
    JTextArea console = new JTextArea(20, 50);
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(6, 50);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton kick = new JButton("Kick");
    JButton ban = new JButton("Ban");
    JButton info = new JButton("Info");

    public ControlPanel() {
        // create our list of players
        list = new JList(model);

        // create our scroll panes
        userspane = new JScrollPane(list);
        consolepane = new JScrollPane(console);

        // add to panel
        panel.add(userspane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(kick);
        panel.add(ban);
        panel.add(info);
        panel.add(consolepane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setTitle("RuneShadows CP");
        //setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new ControlPanel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE** - with positioning

Keep in mind also, with `BorderLayout` you need to specify a position for every component you add or else it will default to `CENTER` and each position an only have one component.  I noticed you trying to add two components to the `CENTER`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ControlPanel extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane userspane;
    JList list;
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JScrollPane consolepane;
    JTextArea console = new JTextArea(20, 50);
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(6, 50);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JButton kick = new JButton("Kick");
    JButton ban = new JButton("Ban");
    JButton info = new JButton("Info");

    public ControlPanel() {
        // create our list of players
        list = new JList(model);

        // create our scroll panes
        userspane = new JScrollPane(list);
        consolepane = new JScrollPane(console);

        // add to panel
        panel.add(userspane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(kick);
        buttonPanel.add(ban);
        buttonPanel.add(info);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(consolepane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(panel);
        pack();
        setTitle("RuneShadows CP");
        //setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new ControlPanel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Got it exactly how I wanted it.

Comment: Keep in mind also, with `BorderLayout` you need to specify a position for every component you add or else it will default to `CENTER` and each position an only have one component. I noticed you trying to add two components to the `CENTER`

Comment: See my **UPDATE** with the correct use of `BorderLayout` positioning